Routh criterion for stability
I am doing exercises in which using Routh's table I find the sign of the poles of a function and then determine its stability.
For example, studying s^3-4s^2+s+6=0 with Routh's table you find two positive and one negative root --> unstable system.
What I am asking is: is this method widely used during control systems theory?
(..I could (even with the help of the internet) decompose s^3-4s^2+s+6=0 into (s+1)(s-1)(s-3)=0 and derive the roots .. it's simpler than Routh's table etc.!)
Maybe the very complicated part lies in this last decomposition? Maybe with experience I will realize that real systems are very complicated and such decomposition is particularly difficult(?) .. so is better/faster apply Routh (?)

For simpler polynomials, direct root finding might be faster and more intuitive. But as the complexity of the polynomial increases, Routh's criterion becomes increasingly advantageous due to its systematic approach and ability to handle higher-order polynomials efficiently.

If you have the numerical transfer function you can immediately find the poles of the system and determine the stability from the get go by solving for when the numerator is zero with respect to \$s\$. No reason to bother with Routh-Hurwitz' criterion. To my knowledge, the Routh table method is obsolete for control theory applications.
Routh-Hurwitz' criterion is useful for determining stability analytically - i.e. in cases where you don't have a numerical expression for the system. For example
Routh-Hurwitz' corollary for a second order system

The system \$H(s) = \frac{P(s)}{s^2+a_1s+a_0} \$ is asymptotically stable iff \$a_1 > 0, a_0 > 0\$.

